# How to colour the arrows in Scatterplot in quiver-plot-in-matplotlib based on a single point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have a code similar to the colored example

"Coloring Quiver Plot
The ax.quiver() method of matplotlib library of python provides an optional attribute color that specifies the color of the arrow. The quiver color attribute requires the dimensions the same as the position and direction arrays.

Below is the code which modifies the quiver plots we made earlier: " From

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quiver-plot-in-matplotlib/

I did not understand the parameter color "color = np.sqrt(((dx-n)/2)*2 + ((dy-n)/2)*2)". I have similar code and I want to colour the arrows in the same way(the far you are from the point the lighter colour you get) lets call the point (a,b)

Any help ?

Comment: Simplify the right-hand-side of the `color=` line you quote until you understand what it's doing, and then build up the equation from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is an error on the website.
They probably meant

```py
color = np.sqrt((dx/2)**2 + (dy/2)**2)
```

It makes more sense. It coloring from the gradient intensity. When their formula gave a color from a criteria without any practical meaning. And `whatever/2*2` is just a waste of good cpu time.
Besides, they did not even bother to explain what the "n" parameter was. And in some version of their code, they even did not define it (some some of their code simply wouldn't even run)

It seems obvious to me that they intended to compute a norm, with `sqrt(x**2 + y**2)`, but mix up `**` and `*`. Then, they discovered that they got an error (because with `*2` instead of `**2` they end up for some coordinates compute the square root of a negative number). But they did not find why. And because the error only appeared for small number, they just added n to x and y, and adjusted that n parameter until it stops failing. Without even explaining why, because, obviously, themselves never manage to find out why their code was failing.

And then, they copied that `(...-n)*2`  in all their other examples, sometimes forgetting to add `n=-2` somewhere in the code, proving that they even did not run their own code after that adjustment was added.

So, long story short: this parameter is a value that is used to choose color (it is not a color, strictly speaking. Not a R/G/B tuple, nor an index in a color table. But a value, that is used to choose a color in a continuous colormap). You can put everything you want in it. They wanted to put an indication of the gradient, failed at it, and random-tuned their formula until they at least obtained a color, even one that made no sense.

As promised a minimal example.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.quiver([1,2,3,2], [1,1,1,0], [0, 2, 1, -3], [-3, -2, 0, 3], [0,1,0,-1]) 
plt.show()
```

It plots 4 arrows (not a nice fields, but the point is to illustrates how it works). whose origin coordinates are taken from the 1st to parameters (so (1,1), (2,1), (3,1) and (2,0)), and direction/magnitude from the 3rd and 4th parameters (so (0,-3), (2,-2), (1,0), (-3,3)). And, since there is a 5th paramter, color is also given (0, 1, 0, and -1)

So, all together, we get,

- at (1,1) a down pointing big arrow (0,-3) of middle color (0)
- at (2,1) a diagonal medium arrow (2,-2) of light color (1)
- at (3,1) a small horizontal arrow (1,0) of middle color (0)
- at (2,0) a big diagonal arrow (-3,3) of dark color (-1)

The color scale is automatic (unless you tune some parameters). Using `[2,3,2,1]` would yield to the same colors. The point is the smallest value get the "darkest" color, and the highest the "lightest".

And "dark" and "light" have a meaning relative to the colormap. So, for default colormap, it is purple to yellow via green.

But to have literally dark and light, you could choose a grey colormap

```py
plt.quiver([1,2,3,2], [1,1,1,0], [0, 2, 1, -3], [-3, -2, 0, 3], [2,3,2,1], cmap=matplotlib.cm.gray)
```

(not advisable without changing background: the arrow at (2,1) being the "lightest" is white, no invisible on a white background here)

So, point is, you do whatever you want with those 5 parameters. As long as they are all the same length (or shape; on the website you quoted, they use 2d arrays, but there is no reason for that: it has nothing to do with the figure being 2d). Just a bunch of X, of Y, of u and v, and of values for the color.
How you compute those values is totally up to you

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative reply. So, can I choose a color of the arrow to be darker if it is pointing to a specific point? And lighter if it is far from that point

Comment: Well, if you want it to be specifically, literally "darker" and "lighter" you will have to play with colormaps (parameter ``cmap``.You can create one, or preferably, choose one among those in matplotlib.cm.*). But, yes. You can choose to give a low value to color to arrows pointing to a point, and high if not.

Comment: quiver just needs 4 parameters. X, Y, u, v, 4 bunch of numbers (of the same size), representing a list of origin points and size of vector. And an additional parameter, color, another bunch of numbers of the same size, representing the color of the vector. I add a minimal example to my answer.